# Monte Carlo simulation of Multifractional Brownian Motion in MATLAB

Tags: monte-carlo, brownian-motion, matlab, fractals, codes

Code under is taken from http://en.literateprograms.org/Monte_Carlo_simulation_(Matlab)

> ```
> nT  = ceil(T/step);
> [s,c] = cov2corr(sigma);
> s   = s * sqrt(step);
> sigma = corr2cov(s,c);
> Sd  = chol(sigma);
> dW  = randn(nT,length(S0)*nb_traj);
> Sd  = repmat({Sd},1,nb_traj);
> Sdb = blkdiag(Sd{:});
> dWc = dW * Sdb;
> c   = repmat(1+mu*step, nT, nb_traj);
> S   = [repmat(S0, 1, nb_traj); repmat(S0, nT, nb_traj) .* cumprod(c + dWc)];
> S   = reshape(S, [nT+1, size(S0,2), nb_traj]);
> if nargout > 1
>    t = [0;step * (1:nT)'];
> end
> ```

But that code won't work. MATLAB is just crashing. 
I need to simulate multiple paths for multifractal brownian motion.

[image: A more generic Monte Carlo]

Is there any code supporting this formula? Thank you))

Comment: crashing @noob2